# How to Pass uniform float array to fragment shader in Qml shadder Effect?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, glsl, shader

Q: How to Pass uniform float array to fragment shader in Qml shadder Effect ?

Its work with regular property like

```
property var myValue: 0.4;
[...]
fragmentShader: "
  uniform float myValue;
  void main()
  {

     vec4 col = vec4(myValue, 0, 0.0, 1.0);
     gl_FragColor = vec4(col);
  }"
```

but no with array of real like .

```
   import QtQuick 2.0


    ShaderEffect {
      id: shader
      width: 400
      height: 400
      property var myArray: [0.4, 0.5, 1.0];
      fragmentShader: "
      uniform float myArray[2];
      void main()
      {

         vec4 col = vec4(myArray[0], 0, 0.0, 1.0);
         gl_FragColor = vec4(col);
      }"

     }
```

Comment: `[0.4, 0.5, 1.0]` That's three elements. You said your array had two.

Comment: it's not working with two elements

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible as of now, you can check and vote for the issue here : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50493

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation and reference

Answer (score 0):

I have searched other solution to reproduce shadereffect behavior with the full advantage of openglcontext and i found that [qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) this solve my problem and now i can send QVector2D array with : `setUniformValueArray()`